# How to check if the user has the right privilege to install db in php

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for asking this, this maybe pretty simple but I'm just starting to learn php - mysql

Btw - Im working on creating an installer that will install and migrate files.

First I want to show the mysql.user table that I query but unable to do this T_T. Then after this I will check if the particular user has enough privileges to create db and insert values.
I have this code:

```
    <?php
    $server_name=$_POST['server_name'];
    $user_name=$_POST['user_name'];
    $user_pass=$_POST['user_password'];
    $database_name=$_POST['database_name'];


    if(!empty($user_name)) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user='".$user_name."' AND host='".$server_name."'";
        #print_r($query);
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        echo $row['user'];
    }
```

and this gives me an error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\dcs-pps\install\check_step3.php on line 34
```

Pls help. Really need to do this for my last requirements in school.

Comment: See if you're getting an error from the mysql_query call. It'll return false if there was an error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you oppened a connection to your mysql server, and that you selected a database like this:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('YOUR_DB_ADDRESS','YOUR_DB_USER','YOUR_DB_PASS');
if ($db === false)  {
  die("mysql_connect error: " . mysql_error());
}
$selected = mysql_select_db('YOUR_DB', $db); 
if ($selected === false)  {
  die("mysql_select_db error: " . mysql_error());
}
```

If you didn't, your MySQL result resource, `$result` might be not valid. When `mysql_query` fails, [it returns `false`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).